# "Changes taking place" vs. "changes that take place"

Tags: relative-clauses, present-participles, ing, that

I proofread quite often and most of the time recognize lots of mistakes, but from time to time I see this usage of the present participle and it always makes me wonder what rules should I apply to see whether it's correct or not. Here are two examples:

1. > the key factor of restructuring is the scale of **changes, taking** place in the company

   I'm not sure, but it seems it must be like this:

   > The key factor of restructuring is the scale of **changes that take place** in the company
2. > Restructuring is a process oriented at maximizing of the equity value of the company by means of internal and external **improvements, 
   >   radically changing** the operation of the company

   and again I want to change that part to

   > **improvements that radically change**

Please explain to me what kind of structure this is and what rules I should follow.

Comment: This is not a gerund. This is a present participle. A gerund is a participle that acts like a *noun*. Which is clearly not the case here. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Here is a picture of a bridge that spans the river.  Here is a picture of a bridge spanning the river.  Why would the second one be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For (1), both alternatives are equally fine except for the comma. It makes no sense and forces the reader to parse the sentence wrong on the first go.

For (2), the first sentence says that it's the restructuring that does the changing (and the comma is fine), while the second says that it's the improvements that do that. Both are equally valid things to say, they are just two different things.